# Generate robot model for openrave

Tags: robotic-arm, ros, robot-model

Is there another way to generate a collada model to work with openrave other than converting an URDF file with ROS' collada_urdf software?

The problem I'm encountering is with the setup needed to use ROS' program (setting up the ros distro and catkin, ecc..).

Since I've drawn the robot in SolidWorks is there a simpler way to generate the needed collada model?

Answer (score 0):

Blender can create COLLADA files for use in robot simulation. The native `blend` file format can be exported to COLLADA through the built-in export tool. There is also a stack exchange website for Blender.

Answer (score 0):

If you've drawn the robot in Solidworks, you can just export to URDF directly. There's a [tutorial on how to do it on the ROS wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/sw_urdf_exporter/Tutorials/Export%20an%20Assembly). There are more details there, but briefly, from the site:

> 1. Open your assembly in SolidWorks.
> 2. Set the position of your joints as you would like them exported
> 3. Click "Tools>Export to URDF". If using 1.5.1 or older will be under "File>Export to URDF" (sometimes its "Extras>File>Export to URDF")